# sendTextFromHtml - Object doesnt support this property or method

Tags: javascript

I am trying to have a flash analog clock in my application and in its corresponding js i am trying to pass a value 'indiatime' which is system time.

```
 document.getElementById('SBI_GLS_Analog_Latest').sendTextFromHtml(indiatime)
```

But this throws a script error in IE saying 'Object doesnt support this property or method'

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: `sendTextFromHtml()` is indeed not a part of any browser implementation I know. What does it do? Where does it come from?

Comment: The error message is telling you exactly what you need to know - IE's DOM elements do not support that method. Your move.

Comment: Possibly see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6723074/send-from-javascript-to-actionscript-ie-problem

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Seems we stumbled over the exact same thing there

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem with getting Flash-Objects in Internet Explorer too.

It seems that you have to select them over the window-object rather than document in IE.
Try this little snippet, where `flName` is the id of the object:

```
function getFlashMovie(flName) {
        var movieName = flName;
        var isIE = navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft") != -1;
        return (isIE) ? window[movieName] : document[movieName];
    }
```

So now you can get the element:

```
var flashElement = getFlashMovie('flash_id');
```

I know that there are nicer ways to check for Internet Explorer, but this quick-fix did the trick for me.